# how to compare datetime in salesforce?

Tags: force.com

How should i compare two datetime in apex class ? After comparison i need to sort this datetime in ascending order.

```
Datetime firstDate = datetime.valueOf(stringdate1);
Datetime secondDate = datetime.valueOf(stringdate2);

long dt1 = firstDate.getTime() / 1000;
long dt2 = secondDate.getTime() /1000;

if((dt1 - dt2) < 0){    
    sortedlist.add(authObject);
}
```

Is it right way to compare the date and time.

Comment: Why not just use `firstDate < secondDate`?

Answer (score 10):

Dates are primitives in Apex and can be compared directly:

```
Datetime firstDate = datetime.valueOf(stringdate1);
Datetime secondDate = datetime.valueOf(stringdate2);

if(firstDate < secondDate){    
    sortedlist.add(authObject);
}
```

I would be cognizant of [timezones and other quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402102/datetime-and-date-comparison), however.

Nitpick: I would lose the "list" in "sortedlist." Help put a stake through the heart of [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Answer (score 0):

**Use sort()**

```
Datetime firstDate = System.now();
Datetime secondDate = System.today();

List<Datetime> sorted = new List<Datetime>();

sorted.add(firstDate);
sorted.add(secondDate);

sorted.sort();

System.debug(sorted); // DEBUG|(2015-12-22 00:00:00, 2015-12-22 09:37:19)
```

**Sort manually**

```
Datetime firstDate = System.now();
Datetime secondDate = System.today();

List<Datetime> sorted = new List<Datetime>();

if(firstDate < secondDate){
  sorted.add(firstDate);
  sorted.add(secondDate);
} else {
  sorted.add(secondDate);
  sorted.add(firstDate);
}

System.debug(sorted); // DEBUG|(2015-12-22 00:00:00, 2015-12-22 09:37:19)
```