# How does one compare the same Day from Datetime in apex?

Tags: apex, date

I need to see if another person has booked for that day. The field is a datetime field.

How does one compare between the two? Do i convert it to a date and compare them?

This stackexchange answer compares and sees if they're the same but doesn't compare the same datetime:

[how to compare datetime in salesforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29523/how-to-compare-datetime-in-salesforce)

Comment: "booked for that day" implies `Date`, not `Datetime`.  I'm confused what you mean.

Comment: Sorry Updated. The custom object has a Datetime field i need to see if it stores the exact date as today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method on the Date class that does this comparison and returns a boolean. You will need to use a method available on the [DateTime](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_date) field to get the date portion to use the .isSameDay method: `DateTime.date(`) or `DateTime.dateGMT()`

Salesforce Documentation: [Date.isSameDay(Date)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_isSameDay)

Given Example:

```
date myDate = date.today();
date dueDate = date.newInstance(2008, 1, 30);
boolean dueNow = myDate.isSameDay(dueDate);
```